# pm-hibernate does not turn off system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hibernate, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to make `pm-hibernate` to work on my Ubuntu 14.04 system. When I invoke

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

display turns off and I can't do anything anymore but computer does not turn off. All I have found in logs is:

```
Mar 17 21:40:25 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009a000-0x0009ffff]
Mar 17 21:40:25 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000effff]
Mar 17 21:40:25 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000f0000-0x000fffff]
Mar 17 21:40:25 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbfda0000-0xbfdd0fff]
Mar 17 21:40:25 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbfdd1000-0xbfdfffff]
Mar 17 21:40:25 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbfe00000-0xbfefffff]
Mar 17 21:40:25 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbff00000-0xdfffffff]
Mar 17 21:40:25 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff]
Mar 17 21:40:25 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf0000000-0xfebfffff]
Mar 17 21:40:25 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec00000-0xffffffff]
Mar 17 21:40:25 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xb4000000-0xb7ffffff]
Mar 17 21:40:25 dmitry-pc kernel: [    2.683676] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0xbfda0000-0xbfdd0fff] (200704 bytes)
Mar 17 21:40:25 dmitry-pc kernel: [    3.887015] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
Mar 18 12:34:48 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009a000-0x0009ffff]
Mar 18 12:34:48 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000effff]
Mar 18 12:34:48 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000f0000-0x000fffff]
Mar 18 12:34:48 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbfda0000-0xbfdd0fff]
Mar 18 12:34:48 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbfdd1000-0xbfdfffff]
Mar 18 12:34:48 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbfe00000-0xbfefffff]
Mar 18 12:34:48 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xbff00000-0xdfffffff]
Mar 18 12:34:48 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff]
Mar 18 12:34:48 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf0000000-0xfebfffff]
Mar 18 12:34:48 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfec00000-0xffffffff]
Mar 18 12:34:48 dmitry-pc kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xb4000000-0xb7ffffff]
Mar 18 12:34:48 dmitry-pc kernel: [    2.683666] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0xbfda0000-0xbfdd0fff] (200704 bytes)
Mar 18 12:34:48 dmitry-pc kernel: [    3.867333] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
```

Comment: Were you able to boot after? I can't get mine past `Loading Initial Ramdisk _`

Comment: Yes I can boot my system after that

Comment: It came up fine after just boring into a live usb. The basic answer to your question is that not all hardware can support Ubuntu hibernation. You should all on askubuntu, not here.

Comment: It worked before, I've been using the same hardware for past two years. Anyway, thanks.